# 40 GHz 1-to-4 power divider and middle amplifier strategy

Tags: power-divider

I have a surface mount amplifiers working at 40 GHz with 7 GHz bandwidth.
I need to create a 1-to-4 power divider and put my amplifier in between and then combine the amplified signal back.

the problem is that the frequency is so large that if I try to do Wilkinson power divider then the SMT resistor shown bellow in between will be inductor in 40 GHz.

The other way I thought is to do multi-section 8.34 tandem, connecting two of them to create 3 dB coupler.

But I cannot connect in tandem two microstrip couplers. Another problem is that using coupler is like this is not very practical on placing the amplifier.

Could any one help me with an idea on how to implement such a thing?

[image]

Comment: You will not be able to implement that with discreet SMT parts. The parasitic capacitance will add losses and make matching quite difficult. You will have to implement a microstrip (or a stripline) power divider.

Comment: It's not very clear exactly what you are doing. Are you going to use a 1:4 splitter, then 4 amplifiers one on each path, then a 4:1 combiner, to make a composite 4x more powerful amplifier? If so, you might want to look at a 'travelling wave' or [distributed amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_amplifier) configuration.

Comment: Hello Lior,i need 1 to 4 brach like power dividing.
what implementation can i use? branchline coupler?i need 7Ghz BW at 40GHZ center frequency .Is there some other alternative?